# Apt Install Ros Kinetic Problem after recent update

Tags: ros, apt, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm having issue installing ros after this update. I'm on ubuntu 16.04.

When I try to `apt install ros-kinetic-ros-core` after using apt update it attempts to fetch python-rospkg 1.1.9 and python-rospkg-modules 1.1.9. Neither of those exist after this update so it just gives me an error about not being able to find them. I'd expect apt update to cause it to search for 1.1.10, but that's not happening and I'm confused as to how to fix this. I have a file in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d for ros called ros-latest.list and it's contents are,

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
```

The exact error message from apt is,

```
Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python-rospkg-modules all 1.1.9-1
Ign:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python-rospkg all 1.1.9-100
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python-rospkg-modules all 1.1.9-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3404:200:237::2 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python-rospkg all 1.1.9-100
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3404:200:237::2 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-rospkg-modules/python-rospkg-modules_1.1.9-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3404:200:237::2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-rospkg/python-rospkg_1.1.9-100_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3404:200:237::2 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330725/apt-install-ros-kinetic-problem-after-recent-update/) by [Mehdi2277](https://answers.ros.org/users/44838/mehdi2277/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1.1.10 is the current package in the repository. If your apt database is up to date you should see that.

http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages

```
Package: python-rospkg
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 17
Maintainer: Ken Conley <kwc@willowgarage.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 1.1.10-100
Depends: python-yaml, python:any (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7~), python-argparse, python-rospkg-modules (>= 1.1.10)
Conflicts: python3-rospkg
Filename: pool/main/p/python-rospkg/python-rospkg_1.1.10-100_all.deb
SHA512: 8a9630ab25dd080d72e229bb034dcea7697dfb3a2b95d95398437eb7c733b31528ba9f454115a0f20530dfc0d531f7a06d54c4defdf7bca0f68f0413989f9d66
Size: 2208
SHA256: df6ec77eb91901d8b8775cd1efd05c86a8b1d75a741d3814f643e13ab1b5e135
SHA1: 269efb678acedaba1a414a9c330ce6eacb8bdb3d
MD5sum: 47969a4120db2f9ef60ce24f628efea5
Description: ROS package library
         Library for retrieving information about ROS packages and stacks.
Homepage: http://wiki.ros.org/rospkg
```

You should make sure to run `apt-get update` again. If you have any trouble after that please edit your question to show the output of `apt-get update` as well as `apt-cache policy python-rospkg`

Depending on your networking situation you may have proxies between you and the server that might be causing issues.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi2277](https://answers.ros.org/users/44838/mehdi2277/) on 2019-08-14**:
I ended up resolving the issue by upgrading to 18.04, so I can't tell exactly what the original problem was.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-19**:
It could be that this is another manifestation of #q325039: `apt` not finding packages because of out-dated indices is one of the symptoms of not having the correct key installed.